# Usage of the term multimodal

Tags: terminology

Afaik, the usage of ***multimodal*** is bifold.

**Usage one**

In statistics, it is used as a prefix for probability distributions with multiple peaks

**Usage two**

In general, it is used for concepts or applications involving multiple domains or models such as combination of CNN, RNN etc.,

Other than these two, is there any usage for the above mentioned term?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia lists quite a lot of alternatives.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal)

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)